# Serverless framework get AWS "function url" from separate function

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-framework

I have a serverless application defined like this

```
service: hello_world

frameworkVersion: '3'

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.8

functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.run
  world:
    handler: handler2.run
    url: true
```

Part of the function `hello` is to hand the function url of `world` to an external api.

How can I get the function url to `hello`, as an environment variable or otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

Have not tested, but according to the following you can use what looks like cloudformation fn + backreferences

https://forum.serverless.com/t/how-do-i-get-the-url-for-a-function-in-my-serverless-yml-file/1386/4

```
custom:
  stage: ${opt:stage, self:provider.stage}
  region: ${opt:region, self:provider.region}

environment:
  URL: { "Fn::Join" : ["", [" https://", { "Ref" : "ApiGatewayRestApi" }, ".execute-api.${self:custom.region}.amazonaws.com/${self:custom.stage}/path/to/resource" ] ]  }
```

Comment: This is good if you're using APIGateway, which for this project I wasn't. I've submitted an answer with my (admittedly not great) solution

Answer (score 0):

You need to know how Serverless is internally referencing the function URLs, which *should* be accessable in this format. You can check this by viewing the resource names in AWS.

```
service: hello_world

frameworkVersion: '3'

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.8

functions:
  fn1:
    handler: handler.run
    url: true
  fn2:
    handler: handler2.run
    environment:
      GRANT_URL_ENDPOINT: !Ref Fn1LambdaFunctionUrl
```

Comment: This doesn't work if your functions need circular urls. When you deploy it "always" uses the same url, so for my full project I just made a deploy script to deploy it twice and capture the urls from the output 